# Hyperlink Click Popups Up JQuery Dialog And Returns Called PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dialog, popup

I'm very sure a variation of this has been asked before, and my asking stems from my elementary knowledge of how it all works. I have been reading and reading and reading, and i'm turning to stackoverflow for some help on my question/problem.

Let me describe to everyone what i'd like.  When a table is build on my webpage via a php include call, that table contains a column called 'Info', and in each row of that column for the table, is a hyperlink in created, called info.  What i'd like to do is, when that hyper link is clicked, i'd like to return in a popup of some kind alert popup, jquery dialog, etc the data that the info link would return if navigating to that page. So in theory, i'm eliminating the navigation and providing that information to the user in a friendly dialog.

So on the index page where everything is happening i have code as follows:

```
include buildtable.php
```

Then in the buildtable.php i'm looping through a query and building a table. the column associated with the link look like:

```
echo '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="anotherpage.php?CheckoutId='.$DataArrDT[5].'&DbSchemaID='.$DataArrDT[2].'&DbId='.$DataArrDT[3].'">Info</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
```

Now the above works if i navigate to that page; however, i'd like to try to display this in a dialog.

My questions are as follows:

1) should i keep the construction of the link as above, or should i change it to something like:

```
echo '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="infopopup" onclick="getInfo();">Info</a>&nbsp;& nbsp;</td>';
```

2) the jquery dialog is confusing me, and i'm not even sure if i'm on the right track...

```
function getInfo(){
var $dialog = $('<div class="blah"></div>')
var $link = $this.val();)
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Information'

    $.ajax {(
                    url:'myphpfile.php',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: 'link=' $link,  
        success: function( data ){  
            $('#<div id section on calling page>').html( data );  
        }//end success
    }); //end ajax

});//end dialog
```

}//end Function

Any help and/or good tutorial links would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this link

```
echo '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="infopopup" href="anotherpage.php?CheckoutId='.$DataArrDT[5].'&DbSchemaID='.$DataArrDT[2].'&DbId='.$DataArrDT[3].'">Info</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>';
```

and use this javascript

```
$('#infopopup').click(function() {
    var url = this.href;
    var dialog = $("#dialog");
    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
    } 

    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
            url,
            {},
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog();
            }
        );
    //prevent the browser to follow the link
    return false;
});`
```

Comment: I modified this slightly because i wasn't able to get it to work with provided info.  I changed $('#infopopup').click(function to .live('click', function(), but regardless a dialog popup was not created... instead i'm getting inline results to the body. My assumption here is the appentTo(body) is whats doing that.  For my current implementation this works.  Thanks again for the help.